# Why is my data inserted twice in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP and MySQL database to do my school project. There is a problem that I encounter when I try to import data in my database. In the 1st table (murid table) it works perfectly, but in the second table (pendaftaran table), it seems to import twice. This is my PHP code. I wonder why my data is inserted twice in the pendaftaran table?

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','darksith');

if(!$conn)
{
    echo 'Not connected';   
}


if (isset($_POST['importbutton'])) {
    $namaFail = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    if ($_FILES['file']['size'] > 0) {
      $fail = fopen($namaFail, 'r');

      while (!feof($fail)) {
        $data = fgetcsv($fail, '0');

        $query = "SELECT * FROM murid WHERE No_Sekolah_Murid = '".$data[0]."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if (empty($data[0] || $data[1] || $data[2] || $data[3])) {
          echo "<script>
              window.alert('Sila isikan semua medan dalam fail!');
              window.location = '';
              </script>";
          //exit();
        } else {

          if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 0) {
            $query1 = "INSERT INTO murid(No_Sekolah_Murid, Nama_Murid, Kelas, Tarikh_Daftar) VALUES('".$data[0]."', '".$data[1]."', '".$data[2]."',NOW())";

            $query2 = "INSERT INTO pendaftaran(ID_Pendaftaran, ID_Pengguna, No_Sekolah_Murid, Kod_Pertubuhan) VALUES('', '$username', '".$data[0]."', '".$data[3]."')";

            mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
            var_dump(mysqli_query($conn, $query1));
            mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
            var_dump(mysqli_query($conn, $query2));


          // echo "<script>
              // window.alert('Rekod berjaya ditambahkan!');
              // window.location = 'import.html';
              // </script>";
          } else {
            "<script>
          window.alert('Rekod gagal ditambahkan!');
          window.location = 'import.html';
          </script>";
          }
        }

      } fclose($fail);
    } 

} else {   
    echo "<script>
      window.alert('Import gagal. Sila cuba sekali lagi!');
      window.location = 'import.html';
      </script>";
    exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: Remove move the var_dumps.

Comment: See about prepared statements

Comment: @Mr.Blue thank you so much. I did not realise the var_dump. Btw why does var_dump make it enter duplicates? I thought var_dump only display variable types and values

Comment: @ChuahHaoMin You were executing mysqli_query() again inside of var_dumps() that's why you got duplicate inserts.

Answer (score 3):

The query is being executed two times.

It's being executed on this line:

```
   mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
```

and then executed again, on this line:

```
   var_dump(mysqli_query($conn, $query2));
```

That call to the `mysqli_query` function executes the function again. That line says "execute mysqli_query function", and then output the return from the function.

In terms of the behavior we observe, those two lines are essentially equivalent to writing:

```
   $foo2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2));
   $foo2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2));
   var_dump($foo2);
```

---

Pattern used in the code in the question appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection. Use prepared statements with bind placeholders.

Little Bobby Tables https://xkcd.com/327/

OWASP Project https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

> It’s somewhat shameful that there are so many successful SQL Injection attacks occurring, because it is EXTREMELY simple to avoid SQL Injection vulnerabilities in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below mentioned code:

```
mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
var_dump(mysqli_query($conn, $query2));
```

to

```
$sqlExecRes = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
var_dump($sqlExecRes);
```